# How is BuildID Macro is incremented in TFS Builds, and how can I make it go like ++?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm working on a project being compiled over a TFS server. The build number format (in the process tab of the build settings) is defined as `$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(BuildID)`. What I can't figure out is how the `$(BuildID)` is incremented. If I queue, say two builds, within the same hour, it will usually increase by one, but not always.

[image: $BuildID weird incrementation]

If it's been ~one week since the last build it might increment by 20 or 40. I haven't figured any pattern yet.

But my real question would be : how can I make it increase by one at each build.

Comment: Do you have Continuous Integration builds running on the same server?

Answer (score 7):

$(BuildID)  is used for the whole team project collection. I assume you have multiple team projects in your collection.

So every build triggerd increments this ID by one (It's basically the primary key of the respective build in the TFS DB).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your build number *is* incrementing by 1 each build, but you're only looking at the list of *your own* builds.  Other people are triggering builds (possibly including the build server, if CI is enabled), and the count is only separate per *build definition*, not per *user*.

That's why a longer delay results in a bigger increment: if you're waiting a week, more builds have been run by other checkins/developers.

If you look at the list of all builds, instead of "My Builds" as in your screenshot, you'd likely see a number that increments by 1 each time.

You can't change this as simply as you hope, because if you make the number "per-user" you'd end up with multiple builds with the same ID.  It's possible to override the part of the build script that creates the build number to include your username and a number - which means your build ID would increment by 1 each time, but each user would have a different build name.  (You'd have builds `DEV_JOHN_123`/`DEV_BOB_123` instead of just `DEV_123`/`DEV_124`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Indeed, this could be the case. But I'm the only one working on/compiling this particular project. There are other projects being compiled on the same server though, but I would be surprised if their compiling was to affect our own project macros.

Comment: So you don't have a CI build, and you don't share the team project or build type with anyone else?  Can you post a screenshot of the "all builds" section from the build explorer?

Comment: Well, it seems like I don't have access to "All builds" from the server, but only to the builds from my own project (that is, my own builds). Anyway, I'll lead some tests this afternoon to see if the other projects are affecting my BuildId.

Comment: Just tested and it seems to be the case: the build id increases by one for every project hosted on the TFS server. Now I'll have to try to make it increase by one for my project only. Anyway, thanks for the cue.

Comment: Im not sure but how its done in 2012 but i believe buildID is build unique id number and is incremented for each build that is run in collection regardless of definition, date or its name.

In 2010 format defaults to where revision is incremental number if there are duplicates for the same build name (for builds for one definition run on the same day)
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

+1 increment would be then be DEV_1 ... DEV_123
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Rev)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **$(Rev)** script to increment by one number. **$(Rev)** can only be used at the end of  your build name string.

Eg. **$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)** build number format would produce for three consecutive check-ins on the same day (if you have continuous integration set):

1. MyProject_20130828.1
2. MyProject_20130828.2
3. MyProject_20130828.3

As you can see the last part was autoincremented on each check-in.