# How to get BuildId in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

When I build my project, I can get `${BuildNumber}` variable.
BuildNumber can be customized by `"UpdateBuildNumber"` activity. In this activity we can use `${BuildId}` to formate `${BuildNumber}`. 
But how to get separately `${BuildId}` variable?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502010/how-is-buildid-macro-is-incremented-in-tfs-builds-and-how-can-i-make-it-go-like

Comment: Note that in the Build XAML, the parentheses are not the squiggly type; i.e.   `(` not `{`

Answer (score 0):

**If you're looking for the BuildNumber:**

Use the `BuildDetail`'s `BuildNumber` property when setting the `BuildNumberFormat` property of the `UpdateBuildNumber` build step.

In the example build XAML below, the `BuildNumberFormat` property is set to:

```
newBuildString + BuildDetail.BuildNumber
```

[image: Build XAML in GUI]

`newBuildString` is a variable, but could also be a string:

`"v1.2.0." + BuildDetail.BuildNumber`

**If you're looking for the BuildID:**

The TFS internal BuildID can be extracted from the URI for the build, as accessed from the `IBuildDetail` object (see above).

This can be accessed using the following [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.linkingutilities.decodeuri.aspx):

```
LinkingUtilities.DecodeUri(BuildDetail.Uri.ToString()).ToolSpecificId;
```

See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab8140a2-a236-40d0-b146-dd8f6f4eb4ce/getting-buildid-value-in-a-tfs-2010-build-workflow-activity?forum=tfsbuild